# Using ASP.NET MVC 2 and model binding with ADO.NET EntityCollections

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-binding, ado.net, model

I found a great tutorial on how to use Model Binding and List, *[Editable Grid / List Binding in MVC2](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/02/27/editable-grid-list-binding-in-mvc2/)*. It shows how to create objects containing lists of type `List<T>`. But when I use the [ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) entity data model I cannot make the this:

```
SomeEntityCollection[i]
```

And thereby I can not make what is done in the tutorial.

Is there a way to work around this? Maybe make the ADO.NET use lists instead, if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I have found to map from [ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) to models is to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). It's a very elegant way to formalize mapping between structures.

From their site:

> AutoMapper uses a fluent configuration API to define an object-object mapping strategy. AutoMapper uses a convention-based matching algorithm to match up source to destination values. Currently, AutoMapper is geared towards model projection scenarios to flatten complex object models to DTOs and other simple objects, whose design is better suited for serialization, communication, messaging, or simply an anti-corruption layer between the domain and application layer.

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused, i  thought ADO.Net data model entity did that for me already. Thats how i use it. BUt the problem lies in the model binding in html forms with EntityCollections.

Comment: If you like the answer, please mark the question complete by clicking on the checkmark.